# Greatest integer function inequality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to show that $[x+y] \geq [x] + [y]$, where $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$.

This is my work so far:

Assume $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$.  Suppose $[x]=m$ and $[y]=n$.  Then $m,n \in \Bbb {Z}$.  So then $m \leq x < m + 1$ and $n \leq y < n +1$.  So then, adding the inequalities gives us $m+n \leq x+y < m+n+2$.

Am I on the right track?  I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Close.  You want to write
$$ x = m+r $$
and $$ y = n+s $$
where we know $r$ and $s$ are in $[0,1)$.

Now you can write
$$
[x+y] = m+n+[r+s]
$$
but $[r+s] \geq 0$ since $r$ and $s$ are non-negative.
$$
[x+y] \geq m+n = [x]+[y]
$$

Comment: I don't understand why you added $r$ and $s$ and why they had to be in $[0,1)$. Wouldn't $x$ and $y$ have to equal integers?